# How to get list of online friends using FQL with facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I have got my friends list after getting logging in on facebook using Facebook connect Java script client API. I want list of my friends that are online at given time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `online_presence` column of the `user` table, which gives the user's current Facebook Chat status. This isn't a foolproof "is this user online right now" but it does serve the general purpose as such. This column is a string which has one of four possible values: `active`, `idle`, `offline`, or `error`. Querying the `friend` table in conjunction with this can yield the result you requested (in this case I consider "online" to mean `active` or `idle`):

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE
  online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')
  AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user_id
  )
```

**UPDATE:**

Note that you need the `user_status` permission to read the user's status and `user_online_presence` and/or `friends_online_presence` permissions for the `online_presence`.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/613631/laphroaig for bringing this up ([Facebook online friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666153/facebook-online-friend)), and to https://stackoverflow.com/users/570958/roozbeh15 for his answer.

Comment: I'm trying it, but 99% of my friend list have online_presence empty. why? any help? i made a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666153/facebook-online-friend