# Checking online users with Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, social-networking

I'm trying to build some kind of a social game in facebook, where I need that every user that has approved my APP is able to receive notifications from me.

When the user approves my App, I save his UID in the DB for future reference.

At some later time, I want to make it possible for other users find partners for a game - so I need a way to pick randomly some user from my DB and check if he's online. Then, send him a message and propose to play with the current player.

So 2 questions:

1. How can I check if some user is online, using Javascript SDK? It seems that in the new Graph API I can't get the users' online status.
2. How can I then send him a message and propose to play the game? When he approves to play - he is being forwarded to the game page.

Many thanks in advance,

Roman

Answer (score 3):

To get the user status you can try FQL, check this answer: [How to get list of online friends using FQL with facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795934/how-to-get-list-of-online-friends-using-fql-with-facebook-api)

About your second question, check this: [how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)