# FQL for getting online friends list- Objective c

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am creating an iPhone app using Facebook api. I have created the app and now I'm getting friends name, uid, sex and profile picture.I have followed the steps in the https://developers.facebook.com  And I need to get the online friends list from my account. I think I need to get get permission first. How can do that? please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out what permissions you need and use the api to ask for the user to grant them (this example asks for the publish_stream permission):

```
//This is an array filled with permissions you need
NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil] retain]; 
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"yourappid" andDelegate:self];


if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSLog(@"Sending facebook connect request");
    [facebook authorize:permissions]; 
}
else {
    NSLog(@"There is already an active FB session");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. and also, how can I logout, from the session?

Comment: I tried with [facebook logout:self]; but working. Should I do something else? Please reply.

Comment: [facebook logout:self]; is all you need to logout

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to prompt your users to grant the `user_online_presence` and/or `friends_online_presence` permissions.

Then you can get the user's friends' online statuses by querying for the `user.online_presence` field via an [FQL Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795934/how-to-get-list-of-online-friends-using-fql-with-facebook-api).