# fire FQL using JQuery or JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile

I have seen examples of fetching data using FQL with the help of PHP Facebook SDK , but is it possible to fire FQL query using Javascript or Jquery as i want to fetch online friend list in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has an extensive [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), which will offer you what you need.

Once you have authenticated the client, you should use the [`FB.api()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) method to launch an API request. In particular, you should be considering the `online_presence` of your users' friends  ([in the `user` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)).

For more info, see the StackOverflow question; [How to get list of online friends using FQL with facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795934/how-to-get-list-of-online-friends-using-fql-with-facebook-api)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [`FB.api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) method of [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

```
FB.api('/fql', 'GET', {q:'YOUR_FQL_QUERY'}, function(response){
  if (response && response.data)
    console.log(response.data);
});
```